# Sending a FormData object cross server

Tags: ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

If I try to send the same form at url in the same server it works.

```
$("#ticketForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);
    for (var p of formData) {
        console.log(p);
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:81/api/saveTicket',

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        //crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        //async: false,
        data: formData,

    }).always(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });

});
```

And this is query string parameters (from chrome console)

```
callback:jQuery32105615105729283254_1491918028896
[object FormData]:
_:1491918028897
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `dataType: 'jsonp'`.
 Try with `dataType: 'json'`